# Why does my data not update when calling one api and updates well when I call another?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to create a real time covid-19 data dashboard using React. The data is coming from the desease.sh api and the global figures change regularly so I am sending a new request to the api end point to get new data using setInterval after a minute. But when that new request happens, the data does not change on my app.

Below is my code to the disease api. Which is not working as expected

```
function CoolTest() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    const getData = async () => {
        try {
            const data = await axios.get("https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/all");
            setData(data.data);

        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    };    
    
    useEffect(() => {
        getData();
        setInterval(()=>{
            getData();
            setData(data => data)            
    }, 120000)
    }, []);

    console.log(data.todayCases)       

    
    return (
        <Container style={{marginTop:'15px'}}>
            <h3>New Cases</h3>
            <p className="text-muted"> {data.todayCases}</p>
            <hr />
        </Container>
    )
}
```

Then using the same code, I tried making a request to the Chuck Norris jokes api, which is working. The Joke changes after every new request.

```
function CoolTest() {
    const [jokes, setJokes] = useState([]);

    const getJokesData = async () => {
        try {
            const data = await axios.get("https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random");
            setJokes(data.data);

        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    };    
    
    useEffect(() => {
        getJokesData();
        setInterval(()=>{
            getJokesData();
            setJokes(jokes => jokes)            
    }, 120000)
    }, []);

    console.log(jokes.value)   

    
    return (
        <Container style={{marginTop:'15px'}}>
            <h3>Chuck Norris Jokes</h3>
            <p className="text-muted"> {jokes.value}</p>
            <hr />
        </Container>
    )
}
```

What am I missing?

Concole screenshot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiIAd.png)

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? You might be getting rate-limited

Comment: See console there is an error, if it is post it

Comment: I have attached a screenshot of the console to above. there is undefined on the same like where i am loggin the output from the api.

Comment: why are you doing `setJokes(jokes => jokes)` ? you are setting a function instead of the data values

Comment: @dev-cc I assumed because I already set the values on jokes in the function getJokesData(); setJokes(jokes => jokes) is simply replacing the old values of jokes with the new values retrieved after the the setInterval. Atleast thats what the tutorial i looked that up said.

Comment: But you already set it in the `getJokesData` function. It looks weird since you are giving a function (jokes => jokes) when it expects an array. If I were you, I remove it and try again. Could you check if the `console.log` inside the `catch` is printing something?

Comment: "_the data does not change on my app._" Why should it? Have you tested loading the API endpoint manually to see whether it is changing? The number of cases simply might not be updated as frequently as you like (i.e. every time you refresh).

Comment: @underscore_d I have been comparing figures from my app to the figures showing on the api endpoint manually. Yes, the data does not check in two minutes but, I had my app open and the api open at the same time, then I observed for about 30 minutes. My app did not automatically update the value of number of cases. But i randomly refreshed the manually open api end point data and it had changed.

Comment: @dev-cc I have tried to remove that. But when I do that, I am ending up with multiple instance of setInterval running. Meaning i am literally getting new data (i.e from the chuck norris api) in seconds instead of the set two minutes and this is causing my browser to freeze after some time. And when i tried with the disease api. Am not getting any new data still.

Answer (score 0):

Data is not changing because **the new data is the same as the previous**.

you can change:

```
const data = await axios.get("https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/all");
setData(data.data);
```

to

```
const data = await axios.get("https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/all");
setData({ todayCases: Math.random() });
```

to see the view is changing.

in your second code api name is api.chucknorris.io/jokes/**random**

and gives you each time a random number that is not equal to the previous.

you can see results is [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/red-dust-y78yz?file=/src/App.js:229-342)

and also change:

```
      setInterval(()=>{
            getJokesData();
    }, 120000)
```

to:

````
      setInterval(()=>{
            getJokesData();
            setJokes(jokes => jokes)            
      }, 120000)```
````

Comment: For the first one, when i changed to setData({ todayCases: Math.random() }); I am successfully getting a number random number. After the interval

Comment: second was working because you are getting random data. if you check devtool/network, you see there is no change in data.todayCases (in first code)

Comment: thats the problem i am trying to solve. Because data is changing on the api. Am able to that when i manually check the disease api end point. I have observed this for period of 30 minutes with too tabs open. One with my app running and console logging the value of todayCase which remains the same, and yet when i randomly refreshed the tab with the open api end point the value for todayCase changed. What could be causing my app not to get the new values even when data at the api changes